# form_for fields disables all javascript elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3.2 application.

On one page I have some javascript to show hide divs.
That works fine and dandy.

However when I add some fields it seems all javascript events are disabled, for the code that worked before.
I can make the events work again, if I remove the fields, but leave the form_for tag.
If I only remove for instance the text area, the events are still gone.

If I move the fields up directly under the form_for tag, it works again

One more hint I found, I have three RWD states, Desktop, Tablet and Phone.
On phone it works! But on the two other states, its does not work.

The form_for tag looks like this:
    `= form_for(@new_note, url: write_new_page_path) do |f|`
and I add fields like this:

```
 = f.label :text, 'how are things today?', :class => 'module-helper'
 = f.text_area :text, placeholder: 'Please write a note here', rows: 5, class: 'required'
```

I did not expect the events to be gone, and I am sure its a rookie mistake.
You can find the entire code here:
https://gist.github.com/khebbie/a29917357552b809a1fe

Comment: do you see any kind of error in browser console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: check you text_area tag. The format is different.


http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag

Comment: Anything in particular you think about?

Comment: @khebbie change this and try once: `= f.text_area :text, {placeholder: 'Please write a note here', rows: 5, class: 'required'}`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: @khebbie Did you get any error? if yes please post it

Comment: could you post your whole view as well as javascript

Comment: https://gist.github.com/khebbie/a29917357552b809a1fe

Comment: what events? Sounds like you need to use event delegation within the javascript if you are dynamically adding elements

Comment: I actually don't add elements, they are all there from the beginning.

Comment: @khebbie Once try by removing all the properties of your test area

Comment: @anusha As I wrote in the post, I can remove the entire textarea and keep the label, and the events are not fired. It is as if just using a f.something disables the events

Comment: @khebbie then try without f something like this `label(:new_note :text)

text_area(:new_note, :text, rows: 5)` I thought your model is new_note if not specify your model name there

Comment: @anusha Great idea, however it didn't work

Comment: Ok, I got a breakthrough, I moved the fields up directly under the form_for statement, and the javascript events started working again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found the answer:
It turned out that the elements were hiding under other elements.
That is why it worked in phone layout.